# Nginx Proxy_pass configuration problem docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a server on hetzner with ubuntu and various dockers installed.
I have configured nginex and each application to porter communicate in ssl. I use only one domain that points to the various addresses of the installed services.

I configured the location /static because emqx when in ssl could not resolve the complete paths to the resources.

now i'm in the situation that also "filebrowser" points to resources with the path /static and i don't know how to correctly address the resources when they are requested by mydomain.net/filebrowser/static on its specific port because there is already an address for the location static.

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mydomani.net;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomani.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomani.net/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location /portainer/    {
        proxy_pass https://SERVERIP:9000/;
    }
    location /emqx/ {
        proxy_pass https://SERVERIP:18084/;
    
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }
    location /static {
            proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1:18084/static/;
         
    }
    
    location /api/v4 { 
             proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1:18084/api/v4/;
    }

    location /node-red/ {
        proxy_pass  https://SERVERIP:1880/;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
    
    location /filebrowser {
        proxy_pass  http://SERVERIP:4443;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_read_timeout 999999999;
    }
    
    }

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomani.net;
        return 301 https://mydomani.net$request_uri;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution would be to patch either piece of software to support a base URL.
If that's not possible, try using different subdomains: emqx.mydomain.tld, filebrowser.mydomain.tld. This is the easiest and best in may regards approach.

Next workaround:

1. mix static files (least recommended)
2. use referer  header to find out which 'static' is needed and proxy using a variable
3. error_page 404 may also help: try one directory, then error page to another.

The first and the third approach won't work if there are matching file names.